# Undefined functions in GLSL 1.5 (GL 3.2): texture, textureLod, textureLodOffset?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I downloaded a GLSL shader example which was written for OpenGL 4.1, and would like to get it working on my computer which has OpenGL 3.2 and GLSL 1.5. However, I can't figure out what to do about some functions that seem like they *should* be there, but aren't:

texture
textureOffset
textureLod
textureLodOffset

From what I can gather online, OpenGL 3.2 and GLSL 1.5 are *supposed* to have those functions, but on my system texture was called *texture2D* and the other functions are missing entirely. Switching all of those functions to use texture2D caused the shader to compile and run, but of course the results were wrong since it ignored the Lod and Offset parameters.

Any ideas on how to get this working? Do those functions exist under a different name, or is there a way to manually re-implement them?

Comment: `textureLod` is a little unique among the ones you listed in that it is only available from certain types of shaders (namely fragment shaders). The other problem is that `texture2D` is deprecated (belonged to OpenGL 2.0 / 2.1's shading language)

Comment: Do you actually have a `#version 150` directive in your shader sources? If not, you fall back to GLSL 1.10 and those functions will not be available.

Comment: I tried at the time, but it didn't recognize the #version directive so I had to remove it.

Comment: @BonzaiThePenguin: Sort of far fetched, but if you have the `#version` directive in your shader code (which you need for using a GLSL version above 1.10), it needs to be the first line in the shader code, and it needs a newline character at the end of the line. The newline is easily missed if you pass in the shader code as a string.

Comment: I'll poke around and see if I can get it to work. If what you're saying is true about defaulting to 1.10 without the #version directive, that would definitely be the problem!

Comment: You were completely right! My entire project was set up around OpenGL 2.1, which is why the #version directive was not recognized. I had to switch the included headers and the pixel format to 3.2 and while it isn't working yet, it now recognizes the missing functions!